# Почему когда я пытаюсь перейти на свою основную страницу меня перенаправляет на другую?

Tags: wordpress

Переносил сайт с одного хостинга на другой

Архитектура папки в которой находился сайт была такой:

```
name.com
     файлы wp
     public_html
           все файлы сайта
```

Почему это было всё так можете не спрашивать я не знаю так как сайт создавал не я.

public_html в данной ситуации это просто папка которая не несёт за собою ничего и тот же эффект был бы если она называлась бы "home_html" и тд
(я всё размусоливаю для того что бы не было недопонимания так как задавал тот же вопрос на других форумах и ни кто ничего не понимал)

Структура очень странная и по этому я решил поднять все файлы сайта на уровень выше и удалить всё не нужное то есть это удалил вторые файлы wp и ненужную папку public_html

И залил сайт на тестовый домен что бы проверить всё ли хорошо и не совершил ли я ошибку своими действиями

По итого всё было нормально, да разумеется из-за переноса были проблемы с сайтом по типу фотографии не показывались или вроде того но это не проблема и легко решаемо по этому я принял решение перенести сайт на нормальный домен и уже там решить все проблемы, но видимо моё "везение" закончилось и теперь при попытке зайти на главную страницу меня переносит в место https://wheelsconcepts.com на https://wheelsconcepts.com/public_html/
ещё раз уточню такой проблемы на тестовом домене не было и всё нормально работало и только когда я перенёс на первоначальный домен и появилась эта проблема.

Я не понимаю где может идти перенаправление так как например в настройках странице указана первая ссылка что я прислал, в базе данных я тоже ничего не нашёл

прошу помогите..

Comment: Постарайтесь создавать читаемые тексты, а не простыни без знаков препинания. Тогда у большего числа людей появится желание вникать в ваш вопрос.

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема в .htaccess, который должен иметь разный вид в зависимости от расположения файлов WordPress: https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/

Comment: @KAGGDesign есть способ как найти место где осуществляется перенаправление или перебить это чем-то? Просто проблемы в .htaccess лично я не нашёл, но сейчас хотя бы временно, но нужно решить данную проблему

Comment: Какие навик "файлы ВП" выше public_html? Какие нафик отдельно "файлы сайта"? Срочно учить основы CMS и структуру файловой системы вебсервера.

Comment: @SeVlad, извините вы читать умеете ? Ещё раз скажу.
1) Сайт не мой
2)public_html это просто папка и ничего больше это не КОРНЕВАЯ папка просто программист писавший сайт по какой-то тупой причине решил назвать так папку, или что хотите сказать что назвать ПРОСТУЮ ПАПКУ public_html невозможно или что ?

Comment: @SeVlad, простите что злюсь просто меня достало по сто раз объяснять людям что public_html это ПРОСТАЯ ПАПКА просто люди как обезьяны с палками стучат и кричат что "public_html корневая папка" , "о боже как ты вообще её удалил?", "о боооже что ты натворил иди срочно учи основы CMS и файловой системы вебсервера", я может и не профессионал далеко, но основы знаю) 
честно все только и могут возмущаться, но ни одного по сути нормального ответа !